# Unpivot in MYSQL?

Tags: table, mariadb-10.3, unpivot, data

Please I need help on how I can transform the data that appears in the attached photo. Maybe Unpivot SQL?

[image]

Comment: Use `UNION/UNION ALL` most likely the best and only way possible in MySQL/MariaDB to unpivot....

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) .. Also the output needs to have a position/order column so you maintain the correct order..

Comment: MariaDB does not yet support LATERAL (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19078, it mentions support for it in MySQL8), so like @RaymondNijland says, UNION / UNION ALL is likely the way to go.

Comment: `LATERAL` was only recently added: [_8.0.14_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html).  But I would be tempted by `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,customer,"Auxiliary" as Aux_type,auxiliary1,value1 
from input_table

union

select id,customer,"Auxiliary" as Aux_type,auxiliary2,value2 
from input_table

union

select id,customer,"Auxdyeing" as Aux_type,auxdyeing1,value3 
from input_table;
```

This should work I guess.